# How do I save a txt file inside a different folder within the project?

Tags: c#, filestream, streamwriter

Suppose I have a folder named "Games".

When I use this code it will save it in the debug folder.

```
FileStream outputFileStream = new FileStream("Games.txt", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(outputFileStream);

writer.WriteLine(textBox1.Text);

writer.Close();
outputFileStream.Close();
```

I would like to save it somewhere inside the Games folder instead. How would I do that?

Comment: Add the path to the filename - i.e., `C:\Games\Games.txt`.

Comment: @Tim What my file path is a bit long since it's deep in my documents?

Comment: If the `Games` folder is in the root of your project, you could also do `..\..\Games\Games.txt`.  Without a path, the file will be saved in the folder that the assembly is executing from - in this case, your debug folder.

Comment: @Tim The thing is, what if I don't want to type C drive? Is there a way so that I can ask it to save somewhere within my project folder just not specifically in the debug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can provide the absolute or relative path along with the filename as follows...

```
FileStream outputFileStream = new FileStream("C:\Games\Games.txt", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
```

or

```
FileStream outputFileStream = new FileStream(@"..\Games.txt", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
```

Good Luck!

Comment: What does the @ symbol do?

Comment: "@" symbol indicates that the string should be treated as a literal, i.e. no escaping. This link should help...http://programmers.bhoomijunction.com/Article/regular-string-literal-and-verbatim-string-literal-in-c-sharp-dot-net-29

Answer (score 2):

Instead of simply putting the filename - `"Games.txt"`

you can append it to a folder inside your working directory - `"Games\\Games.txt"`,

or an absolute filename path (not recommended) - `"C:\\Games\\Games.txt"`

Comment: The directory wasn't found.

Comment: @puretppc maybe replace the double-backslash with single backslashes. However, I tend to use doubles, since it will always be treated as a literal backslash. Also, you may want some code beforehand to create the directory if it doesn't exist. I'm not sure exactly how to do that in Java, but I know you can.

Answer (score 1):

Just pointing the first argument with your path file. Let's say, you want to save into:

```
"C:\Another Folder\Games.txt".
```

You could try this code:

```
string pathFile = @"c:\Another Folder\Games.txt";

FileStream outputFileStream = new FileStream(pathFile, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
```

Make sure you have "Another Folder" in drive C. Thanks.